# After Effects - Align multiple objects / layers

Tags: alignment, after-effects

I have a text layer and a composition. How can i align those 2 in the center? When I select them and use the align window, I choose Align layers to composition and click center, what I got is both layers are in the center overlapping each other...

I know in photoshop and illustrator etc. you can group layers and align them in the center, but because I have a composition and text layer I can't group them... I know also I can create a rectangle as wide as the total length of the 2 layers and align that in center and then the layers but there should be a easier way.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure if I understand your question, but you can group the layers together by creating a null object and parenting each layer to it.